# Reshape Spark DataFrame from Long to Wide On Large Data Sets

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to reshape my dataframe from long to wide using Spark DataFrame API. The data set is the collection of questions and answers from student's questionary. It's a huge data set and the Q(Question) and A(Answer) approximately range from 1 to 50000. I would like to collect all the possible pairs of Q*A and use them to build columns. If a student answered 1 to Question 1, we assign a value 1 to column 1_1. Otherwise, we give it a 0. The data set has been de-duplicated on S_ID, Q, A.

In R, I can simply use dcast in the library reshape2 but I don't know how to do it using Spark. I have found the solution to pivot in the below link but it required a fix number of distinct pairs of Q*A. 
http://rajasoftware.net/index.php/database/91446/scala-apache-spark-pivot-dataframes-pivot-spark-dataframe

I also tried concatenating Q and A using user-defined function and them apply crosstab However, I got the below error from the console even though so far I only test my code on a sample data file-

```
The maximum limit of le6 pairs have been collected, which may not be all of the pairs.  
Please try reducing the amount of distinct items in your columns.
```

Original Data:

> S_ID, Q, A
>   1, 1, 1
>   1, 2, 2
>   1, 3, 3
>   2, 1, 1
>   2, 2, 3
>   2, 3, 4
>   2, 4, 5

=> After long-to-wide transformation:

> S_ID, QA_1_1, QA_2_2, QA_3_3, QA_2_3, QA_3_4, QA_4_5
>    1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0
>    2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1

```
R code.  
library(dplyr); library(reshape2);  
df1 <- df %>% group_by(S_ID, Q, A) %>% filter(row_number()==1) %>% mutate(temp=1)  
df1 %>% dcast(S_ID ~ Q + A, value.var="temp", fill=0)  

Spark code.
val fnConcatenate = udf((x: String, y: String) => {"QA_"+ x +"_" + y})
df1 = df.distinct.withColumn("QA", fnConcatenate($"Q", $"A"))
df2 = stat.crosstab("S_ID", "QA")
```

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: _Q(Question) and A(Answer) approximately range from 1 to 50000_ - does it mean you have 50000  or 50000^2 QA pairs / columns?

Comment: @zero323 The Q and A both have tens of thousands values. For the pairs, I believe we have less than ten times of that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is faulty by design for two reasons:

1. You replace sparse data set with a dense one. It is expensive both when it comes to memory requirements and computations and it is almost never a good idea when you have a large dataset
2. You limit ability to process data locally. Simplifying things a little bit Spark data frames are just a wrappers around `RDD[Row]`. It means that larger the row the less you can place on a single partition and in consequence operations like aggregations are much more expensive and require more network traffic.

Wide tables are useful when you have a proper columnar storage when you can implement things like efficient compression or aggregations. From the practical perspective almost everything you can do with wide table can be done with a long one using group / window functions.

One thing you can try is to use sparse vector to create wide-like format:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer
import sqlContext.implicits._

df.registerTempTable("df")
val dfComb = sqlContext.sql("SELECT s_id, CONCAT(Q, '\t', A) AS qa FROM df")

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("qa")
  .setOutputCol("idx")
  .fit(dfComb)

val indexed = indexer.transform(dfComb)

val n = indexed.agg(max("idx")).first.getDouble(0).toInt + 1

val wideLikeDF = indexed
  .select($"s_id", $"idx")
  .rdd
  .map{case Row(s_id: String, idx: Double) => (s_id, idx.toInt)}
  .groupByKey // This assumes no duplicates
  .mapValues(vals => Vectors.sparse(n, vals.map((_, 1.0)).toArray))
  .toDF("id", "qaVec")
```

Cool part here is you can easily convert it to `IndexedRowMatrix` and for example compute SVD

```
val mat = new IndexedRowMatrix(wideLikeDF.map{
  // Here we assume that s_id can be mapped directly to Long
  // If not it has to be indexed
  case Row(id: String, qaVec: SparseVector) => IndexedRow(id.toLong, qaVec)
})

val svd = mat.computeSVD(3)
```

or to `RowMatrix` and get column statistics or compute Principal Components:

```
val colStats = mat.toRowMatrix.computeColumnSummaryStatistic
val colSims = mat.toRowMatrix.columnSimilarities
val pc = mat.toRowMatrix.computePrincipalComponents(3)
```

**Edit**:

In Spark 1.6.0+ you can use `pivot` function.

Comment: "In Spark 1.6.0+ you can use pivot function."  Actually that's unhelpful with large data sets due to 10K limit of number of columns. That the developer at Databricks also said it's probably not safe to change the default limit is suggestive of an algorithmic limitation to the pivot capacity as it is written.  The toy example is of a recommender system, which is nice but falls way short of the mark because much more than 10K items definitely need to be handled by some recommenders.  For example I need 100K items to begin to be useful in my recommender.